# Action when website changes

Tags: c#, winforms, redirect, action

how can i make action when link in WebBrowser1 changes?
I tried to do `if(webbrowser1 == https://www.google.nl/intl/en/about/)`but it doesn't work

I mean at startup in WebBrower1 is http://www.google.com and when i click something in this WebBrowser1 link changes, for example https://www.google.nl/intl/en/about/ and my question is, how can make an action (MessageBox.Show("you are here"); when i'm on main google page and i'm go to about page

This is "Windows Forms Application"

Comment: What is the technology Windows Forms or WPF ?

Comment: Windows Froms Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do it using [`Navigated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

You can also find an example and how to catch and redirection moment here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx

I believe this example will help you:

```
// Shows ModalWindow upon navigation.
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender,
    WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you are here:" + WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs.Url);
}
```

Comment: I want to know how can i do this, and not where can i find this :)

Comment: @KacperSerewis i've added code example to my previous answer.